# Decrypt Upcoming Text Flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, aes

I just want to enter string and on press decrypt it.
this is my app, but I can't decrypt the string cause `_cipher.text` type 'String'. it's type should be 'Encrypted'

```
onPressed: ()  {
                setState(() {
                  final k = Key.fromUtf8('1234567891011123');
                  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
                  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(k));
                  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(_cipher.text, iv: iv);
                  _plain.text = decrypted;
                });
              },
```

I don't want to use `final crypted = encrypter.encrypt(_cipher.text, iv: iv);` cause it comes encrypted.

Comment: could you describe exactly what error you are getting?

Comment: This code for decrypt final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(_cipher.text, iv: iv); but it's not accept _cipher.text this is controller for TextField. it's accept encrypted type only. how I convert upcoming text to type encrypted to be decrypt. hope u understand,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just directly decrypt the string. You need to pass in the encrypted one into decrypt otherwise it would give block size error in most of the cases.

```dart
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final cipher = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
  final k = Key.fromUtf8('1234567891011123');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(k));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(cipher, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(encrypted.base64);
  print(decrypted);
}
```

If you have manually set the cipher as `base16` or `base64` string, you can do this :

```dart
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final cipher = 'Xg4+gtUDU0Hd9uMUWU7IJtjxvocKzIOJwumyzbY5n40=';
  final k = Key.fromUtf8('1234567891011123');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(k));

  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(cipher), iv: iv);

  print(decrypted);
}
```

Edit: If you are taking the cipher input from user, you need to validate that using the encrypter if it's a `base16` or `base64` only then you can continue to decrypt using `Encrypted.fromBase64(cipher)` or `Encrypted.fromBase16(cipher)`

Comment: It already comes encrypted I can't pass into encrypted. otherwise it will give me a wrong value when decoding.

Comment: Yeah but it comes as a string right, try using the `Encrypted.fromBase64()` or `base16` methods. It should decrypt fine. These methods do not encrypt the string again they just convert it into the `Encrypted` object.


Like in the above snippet I used a `base64` encrypted string as `cipher` and converted `String` to the `Encrypted` object using the method.

Comment: Ok, I will try, thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)